# Multiple spaces created when using centeralign exec command in IE11

Tags: javascript, iframe

i am applying orderedlist then applying justifycenter using exec command in frame. on doing this getting some white spaces between text only in IE11. Any solution to this?

```
Code:
<iframe id="myFrame" runat="server"></iframe>
<input type=”button” id=”but1” onclick=”iframecommands()”/>
<script>
function iframecommands(){
var oDocument = $get('<%=this.myFrame.ClientID%>').contentDocument;
oDocument.execCommand(“insertorderedlist”, false, null);   
oDocument.execCommand(“justifycenter”, false, null);   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps a picture and a copy of the rendered HTML would help?¨

Comment: Generated Html:<html><head></head><body><ol><li><div align="center">text1</div></li><li><div align="center">text2</div></li><li><div align="center">text3</div></li></ol></body></html></iframe>